# remove credit card information Packing Slip magento

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I want to remove Credit card information from packing slip.

I try in `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment\Packaging.php` file and all related files to remove this but no success.

Answer (score 1):

We can edit all information by edit in

```
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstract.php
```

but this is core file so first move it to your `local` folder

```
app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstract.php
```